# All images are not displayed in facebook share button

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

I am having one problem in my Facebook share button.

I have 8 images in my current post and all the images are greater than the size of 200x200.

But when i click on the Facebook share button it will only displayed 3 images out of 8 from which we can choose thumbnail.

I have also googled for this problem and according to many suggestion I have also reviewed

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug link for the debugging the problem. But there also all the 8 images are displayed properly.

Any help would be appreciable.

Thanks.

Comment: Facebook seems to have limited the maximal amount of images displayed in the share dialog to three a while ago.

Comment: @CBroe : Thanks for your reply. But i am bit confused because of the random behavior by FACEBOOK. Because in one post it displays all the 8 images and in another post it just don't.

Really its beacoming headache for me.

Comment: How are you invoking the share?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a great question, but I think the answer can disappoint you.

**Short answer:** far I know and searched, you can't do that. 
**Long answer:** you can optimize this scenario with some good static images - or if you can be more creative, dinamically images.

---

## The first tip

Add a static image to **every** share. You can do that adding Open Graph Meta Tags inside your `head` section of HTML:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.myawesomesite.com/logo.jpg"/>
```

With the code above you'll say to Facebook **always** show this image as an option in Share button. According to [Facebook documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/checklist/) is recomended use images with at least 1200 x 640 pixels, because this will share a post with a large image. 
**Following is the preview of one post with the recomended dimensions:**
[image]

**And now a post with a small image:**
[image]

## The second tip

In [this post](http://www.clickonf5.org/5536/how-insert-custom-image-thumbnail-facebook-link-sharing/) I found a possible good solution for your problem. The author used the same principles of the previous tip, but he used another practical way to do that.

**He used the following tag:**

```
<link rel="image_src" href="http://myawesomesite.com/logo.png" />
```

This tag is almost the same the previous one, but I think `rel="images_src"` can be a interesting thing. The `link` tag is applied in the head section of the website too (acording to [W3C page](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_link.asp)), but I think you can lie to Facebook, because they're bad guys and don't provide a good API.

I was wondering - and this is just a supposition - why not try apply `image_src` as ID of your post / website images? I can't test this currently, but for now is the best thing I can think.

---

## Conclusion:

Facebook isn't very good in a lot of different ways, and they don't provide everything we need - like this interesting function. But maybe we can fool the Facebook using some strange techniques.

If you don't want test things like this, the only way you can choose images to share is giving to your page the static OpenGraph Meta Tags of the first tip.

I expect it helped something - sadly I think this is the best answer for your question.