# Facebook meta info does not displays in recommendation box

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

I have a problem with Facebook recommendation box(feed)

Here is my code:

```
 <div id="fb-plugin">
<div class="fbpl-header">
    <div class="fbpl-header-bg">
        <h3 style="margin-bottom: 3px; padding-left: 10px; margin-left: 0px;">P1 on Facebook</h3>
        <iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=http://www.policeone.com&layout=button_count&show_faces=false&width=217&action=recommend&font=tahoma&colorscheme=light" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowTransparency="true" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:217px; height:25px"></iframe>
    </div>
</div>
<iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/recommendations.php?site=www.policeone.com&amp;width=217&height=2030&header=false&colorscheme=light&border_color=%23FFFFFF&ref=homepage" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border: 1px solid #ECEFF4; overflow:hidden; width:217px; height:2030px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
```

Some articles has no image and description(like [this](http://www.policeone.com/edged-weapons/articles/6190273-2-in-critical-condition-12-more-wounded-in-texas-campus-stabbing/?fb_ref=homepagea))
I checked article pages in Facebook debugger and not found any serious error(only about rel='canonical' but other page has the same error and works fine)
Any idea how to solve this?

PS it looks like [in this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18982178/all-images-are-not-displayed-in-facebook-share-button) question the same problem.

Comment: That is not the Recommendations plugin, but a simple like button. And since you are only using it to like your site's base URL, I can't see the connection to a special sub-page of your site.

Comment: @CBroe sorry, I forgot to copy second iframe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug. I made a bug report to [facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1428420057370473)